# Placing openInfoWindowHtml to an array of Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I had a problem in placing an openInfoWindowHtml in my array of markers. Without the addListener inside the for loop, the map.addOverlay(markerArray[i]) works fine. What is wrong in my code? Thanks!

```
function addMarkers(){
        var tempMarker;
        var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
        blueIcon.image = "http://www...com/.../.png";

        // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
        markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };
        for(ctr=0;ctr<default_address.length;ctr++){
            tempLatLng = new GLatLng(default_address[ctr][0], default_address[ctr][1]);
            tempMarker = new GMarker(tempLatLng,markerOptions);
            GEvent.addListener(tempMarker, "click", function()
                {tempMarker.openInfoWindowHtml("HI")});
            markerArray.push(tempMarker);
        }
            displayMarkers();

    }
    function displayMarkers(){
        map.clearOverlays();
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
            map.addOverlay(markerArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `marker.openInfoWindowHtml`, but what is `marker`, it's not defined anywhere in this function.  Should that probably be `markerArray[i].openInfoWindowHtml` instead?  I'm assuming markerArray is a global variable containing marker objects.

Update: as to the problem with all the markers opening their infowindows at the position (and with the content) of the last marker, this should work.

```
function addMarkers(){
    ...
            for(ctr=0;ctr<default_address.length;ctr++){
                tempLatLng = new GLatLng(default_address[ctr][0], default_address[ctr][1]);
                tempMarker = new GMarker(tempLatLng,markerOptions);

                // add an event listener for this marker
                bindInfoWindow(tempMarker, "HI");

                markerArray.push(tempMarker);
            }
}

// create a new global function for this
function bindInfoWindow(marker, html) {
     GEvent.addListener(tempMarker, "click", function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html)
     });
}
```

Comment: im so dumb.. but i had a new problem.. when i click on the markers, the infowindows pops out of the last marker placed, not on the each marker in the map.. why is that so? i edited my code above.. thanks

Comment: It's because you're setting the event listener within a loop.  I'll update my answer with some code that should fix this.

Comment: thank you so much! i am so glad that it worked well! thanks again!